# keyword "sleep" not working in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using robot framework with selenium2Library .While using sleep 30s getting the below error as

```
No keyword with name 'Sleep 30s' found. Did you mean:
    BuiltIn.Sleep
```

Any dependent library I missed to include

Comment: try with `2 spaces` between `Sleep and 30s`

Comment: Working as expected Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with `2 spaces` between `Sleep and 30s`

Comment: with AT LEAST 2 spaces. Some people prefer to use 4 spaces as delimiter.